# Why are the conditions for optimality different for A* tree and graph search?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, search-algorithms, heuristics

I am unclear as to why the conditions for optimality for A* search are different for graph search and tree search. When discussing conditions for optimality for A* search in Russell and Norvig's *Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach* they say:

> The first condition we require for optimality is that $h(n)$ be an admissible heuristic.
>
> ...
>
> A second, slightly stronger condition called **consistency** (or sometimes **monotonicity**) is required only for applications of A* to graph search.

Why is consistency only required for A* graph search and not A* tree search? Why are the conditions for optimality different for the two types of search?

Comment: Think about what the major difference is between traversing a tree and traversing a graph: in a tree there is *only one path between two nodes*. In a graph there can be many paths between nodes, some of which are more expensive than others.